# Identification of a bird on the beach of a small lake

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Last December in France (lake of Divonne, Ain) I took a picture of this bird looking for some food on the beach of the lake.

[image: side-left]
[image: side-right]
[image: front]
[image: back]

It looks like a specimen of the genus `Anthus` (Family `Motacillidae`) but as these specimen are quite difficult to identify (especially winter time), I would like to have some confirmation.

By the picture I found on different Internet sites, my potentials guess are (by order of confidence):

1. Water pipit (Anthus spinoletta)
2. Meadow Pipit (Anthus pratensis)
3. Buff-bellied Pipit (Anthus rubescens)
4. Eurasian rock pipit (Anthus petrosus)

The `Eurasian rock pipit` could be present in the region while migrating but this is the less probable in my opinion.

Comment: *Anthus spinoletta* seems to be the way to go. It's feather patterns and beak shape are so identical to the one that you have posted. Considering that this was taken in December in France, it definitely matches with the  [seasonal locations](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Anthus_spinoletta_mapcomm.png) of *Anthus spinoletta*.

Comment: I agree with @Twisted Genes it's a water pipit no doubt.

Comment: if someone would post an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score -1):

**Water pipit**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_pipit

I agree with what was discussed in the comments and don't like open questions.

Comment: i understand that the quality of the answer is not high. but when you down vote please let me know why. the question is still open and needs to be answered. (in this community seems to be stricter rules than I'm used to from other stack exchange communities)